# Add an independent resizeable container around Text in KonvaJs

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

I have gone through how [Konva Labels](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/shapes/Label.html) work. But resizing a tag in this example resizes the text as well. I want the text to wrap or stay the same size on decreasing and increasing the container width respectively.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like behavior if `Konva.Label` shape you can use `Konva.Text` and `Konva.Rect` instead.

In that case, you have full control of rendering shapes. Optionally you can wrap them into `Konva.Group`.